# Can't figure out why object is deallocated prematurely

Tags: ios, swift

I'm implementing a very simple table view.

When creating the view, the code is this:

```
func selectFolder(path: String) {
    var folderViewController = UITableViewController()
    var dataSource = folderViewData(path: path)
    folderViewController.tableView!.dataSource = dataSource // note I've confirmed that tableView is instantiated at this point
    navController.pushViewController(folderViewController, animated: true)
}
```

My data source is very simple; the init() looks like this:

```
class folderViewData: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var rootFolder:String

    init(path:String) {
        rootFolder = path
        DPLog("initializing folderViewDelegate")
        super.init()
    }

     <dataSource methods snipped>
}
```

When this is run, I get an error due to referencing a deallocated object. When I run Instruments looking for zombies, I get this error:

> An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated
>   'dpScheme.folderViewData' object (zombie) at address: 0x7ff6516f5cf0.

I can't figure out how to get the Instruments information as plain text, and I don't have enough reputation to post images. The short description is that the method "selectFolder" retains "folderViewData" once and releases it twice.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep your data source around somehow and the weak reference the tableView has to its dataSource property is not enough. Once the local variable in `selectFolder` goes out of scope the data source is deallocated.

A very common solution to this problem is to put a strong property in the class where `selectFolder` resides and assign the data source to that property so it'll stay around.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the dataSource property was weak. Seems rather cumbersome to keep the dataSource as a property, because there will be (potentially) several of them, as the user navigates a folder hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

The table view has a weak reference to the data source.  Since you pass in the data source and no other object holds on to it strongly after the method ends, it will be deallocated.  Perhaps subclass UITableViewController with a strong data source property so there will be a strong reference to it.

Comment: You should definitely not subclass to make the data source strong. This is just ASKING for a strong reference cycle to occur in the future.

Comment: Just curious - how?  Once the controller was deallocated wouldn't the data source be deallocated too?

Comment: In this specific case, maybe. The dataSource property is weak for a reason. Say someone else inadvertently uses your subclass later and doesn't use it exactly like this, you'd get a memory leak. Think about what would happen if the presenting view controller were the data source instead of some third object. The presenting view controller could (and most likely does) have a strong reference to the presented view controller, and now with the strong data source reference, the reverse is now also true. Thus creating a strong reference cycle.

Comment: Yeah since it was just an external data source object it's self I figured it was a fair solution (probably should have clarified that you should not overwrite the existing data source property and instead have a different one in the view controller subclass).  Definitely agree regarding the data source as the view controller.